# Custom Web part based on search object model to query accross site collections

Tags: development, web-part, search, cross-site

I'm looking for examples how to build a web part (code) that queries all doc libs in a web application (Done by a created search scope, a scope exists with all the docs from all doc libs) and displays the last 10 created documents.

What's the best method to use? Is FullTextSqlQuery sqlQuery = new FullTextSqlQuery(SPContext.Current.Site); a valid option or should I use LinQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FullTextSqlQuery is a valid approach (requires SharePoint Server). You could also consider the KeywordQuery class.

Link on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647394.aspx).

[Example code](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2010/08/my-tasks-web-part-search-driven-cross.html) for tasks list (class derived from search web part).